# What is the best practice for serving static files in Django currently

Tags: django, django-templates

I've found plenty of advice for how to tackle static files in Django 1.x.  Is there a best practices way to go about doing so?

Comment: No, it doesn't have a release if that is what you mean... Question changed so it actually makes some sense. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are may approaches to serving static files in Django, but Django 1.3 introduced a new option to handle them.  Basically, you can define specific directories at a project level or at an app level that contain static media.  Then via a management command, 'collectstatic',  you can copy all of the static files in your project directory to a separate directory (likely external to your project) that is served by your webserver.  This solves a lot of complications of the previous approaches.

1) It allows 3rd party apps to easily include static files in a standard way.  No more creating symlinks from your webserver directory to locations inside of individual python/django modules.

2) It gives you more control over where your webserver can host its static files.  For example, you can define all of your static media inside of you project under version control, but then copy it all to an external location anywhere on the filesystem.  This prevents having to point your webserver to a location inside of your project.

3) Is splits out static media that that will never change from static media that is uploaded by a user using something like a FileField.  This is good because you likely want to keep site-level static media in version control (to be installed on your dev servers), but user-submitted content will upload to a different directory (unlike versions of django prior to 1.3).

I think this functionality used to be a 3rd party module that was merged into core.

Here are the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Basically there are a few new settings.py variables:

STATIC_ROOT - This is a directory on your filesystem that will be served by your webserver.  When you run ./manage.py collectstatic, all of the static files from your project and it's apps will be copied into the directory that you specify here.

STATIC_URL - This is the url that you will set to represent what url base your content will be based from.  If you set this value to "/static/", then "/static/" will prefix all urls of static media that included.  You will also use this variable in your templates.  For example, in your template, you could specify something like:

```
    <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}logo.png">
```

The STATIC_ROOT settings variable specifies where static files are copied to, but you also need to provide a location of where static files are copied from.  This can be done by creating a directory in your individual Django apps called "static//", similar to what you would do for templates within an app.  Upon running the collectstatic command, Django will copy all of the static files from all of the "static/" directories in all of your apps to the STATIC_ROOT directory.  You can also use the STATICFILES_DIRS settings variable to define project-level directories to copy static media from.

Though there are many ways to serve static media, I think this is a nice api set in place by Django that will help with better integrating 3rd party modules.  The fact that this feature is now included in core could give some indication that this approach may have gained some momentum.

Hope this helps,
Joe